# Android ListView clicking a single item gets all items clicked for the listview's selector

Tags: android, android-listview, android-selector, android-background

I have a ListView called AmazingListView and I assign a selector to this ListView. For example, in Android 4.1.2, there is no problem, but in Android 2.3.6, when I clicked an item, all items appears as clicked. In click event and invocation of specified method, there is no problem. I think this is originate from selector. I am putting my list view and selector below, any help is appreciated:

```
<com.foound.widget.AmazingListView
    android:id="@+id/amazing_lv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector_menu_list_view"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>
```

---

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/fff42f2d"/>

</selector>
```

And this is the color specified in the selector:

```
<color name="fff42f2d">#fff42f2d</color>
```

Also maybe this "getAmazingView" method can be needed:

```
@Override
    public View getAmazingView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View res = convertView;
        if (res == null) res = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.menu_item, null);

        // set background of this item text view
        Bitmap itemBmp = aUrl;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
            res.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), itemBmp));
        } else {
            res.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), itemBmp));
        }

        TextView lName = (TextView) res.findViewById(R.id.lName);
        TextView lYear = (TextView) res.findViewById(R.id.lYear);

        Items composer = getItem(position);
        lName.setText(composer.title);
        lYear.setText(composer.summary);

        return res;
    }
```

When not clicked:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/iu3epknzutpa4jq/device-2014-02-21-175429.png

When clicked:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/xv9285pcb7wuzp9/device-2014-02-21-175449.png

When

Thanks..